# Problem in SSRS with Matrix headings for non-data fields

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Hi I have been working on a large matrix which displays the results of a stored procuedre with date fields for the dynamic columns. Prior to the dynamic columns i have several other columns of identifiers for the data. The problem i have is when i try and add column headings (in the tableheading textbox) for the identifiers i need to use spaces to pad the text so that the heading appear in the correct place, this works fine in preview mode, but when i publish the report the final version always has the padding spaces removed. This results in the text all appearing in one bunch on the left of the matrix. I have tried using individual text boxes but these then appear after the Matrix and not over the appropriate columns. Does anyone have any other ideas i might try? Thanks Jon

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here: are you trying to add a heading to the row groups?

Comment: Sorry ZalZaw, it appears to be a rendering error with overlapping objects. By moving the text boxes so they do not overlap the matrix they appear fine. Thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a rendering error with overlapping objects. By moving the text boxes so they do not overlap the matrix they appear fine.